# PHP plus or minus 10 randomly to a variable

Tags: php

I have `"windfr"` variable what has a value. For example 310. I would like to create a new variable what is `"windfr" + or - 1`0

```
$windfr = 310

$rand = rand(0,1);

if($rand == 1){ ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ways to do this one is

```
$windfr = 310;
$windfr += 10 * [1,-1][rand(0,1)];
echo $windfr;
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1026996)

Answer (score 1):

```
$windfr = 310;
$rand = rand(0,1);

if($rand == 1){ 
   $windfr += 10;
}
else {
   $windfr -= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple if/else statement:

```
$windfr = 310

$rand = rand(0,1);

if($rand == 1) $newvar = $windfr + 10; else $newvar = $windfr - 10;
```